# mongoose not projecting like docs say it should

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am experiencing some frustration - trying to return an nested array using findOne

with a model that looks like this

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    studies: []
}
```

Can someone tell me why a mongoose findOne is returning the _id field when I have not specified it?

```
module.exports.getStudies = function( id, callback ) {

    const query = {
        '_id': id
    };

    User.findOne( query, 'studies', callback );

}
```

this is returning

```
{
    "studies": [1,2,3],
    "_id": "5a9ccf7deccccc36d88b36ac"
}
```

when I am expecting

```
[1,2,3]
```

I apologize for the abrupt sounding tone of this question - I've just be at this a while and cannot make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id` always return by default, you have to exclude it from the query.

```
module.exports.getStudies = function( id, callback ) {

    const query = {
        '_id': id
    };

    User.findOne( query, { studies: 1, _id: 0 }, callback );
}
```